# keep drop down list updated as long as the page is open

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu in a PHP page, listing the files in a public directory.

How do I keep this list updated when users add or remove files from this directory?

Comment: please add your codes to question !

Comment: with jquery but you should atleast attempt a try or research abit better because this is a crappy question imho. with a ajax call you can update the list without having to refresh the entire page.... happy googling

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

Based on the comments, the following HTML code contains all you need for a basic working example.

To test it, just copy+paste the code into a new HTML file, save changes and put the file in a folder on your web-server where it is puplically accessible (like "docroot"), then navigate to it with your web browser.

Change the code as you see fit, note the file-name used for your text-file that contains the names in the code below is called: 'file.txt'; so, just change this as you like.

The `overrideMimeType` method makes sure that the contents is "plain text".

**here's the demo**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body
            {
                font-family:Arial,Helvitica,Sans;
            }

            .item
            {
                width:256px;
                padding:0.5em;
                background:#EEE;
                border:1px solid #DDD;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function load(path,call)
            {
                var sock = new XMLHttpRequest();

                sock.open('GET',path);
                sock.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
                sock.addEventListener
                (
                    'load',function()
                    {
                        call(this.responseText);
                    }
                );

                sock.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="item">demo</div>
        </div>

        <script>
            setInterval
            (
                function()
                {
                    load('file.txt',function(text)
                    {
                        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
                        var tags = (menu.innerHTML).split('demo');

                        menu.innerHTML = '';

                        (text.split("\n")).forEach(function(file)
                        {
                            menu.innerHTML += (tags[0] + file + tags[1]);
                        });
                    });
                },
                1000; // refresh every 1 second(s)
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Suggestions**

I would rather suggest saving this "text file" as "JSON", that way you won't need to explicitly parse the contents, you can then just set the responseType (in that "load" function) as 'json' and it will be parsed automatically.

Anyway, the code above should work for you, please comment if clarification is required.

Comment: I _kind-of_ posted this anser as a joke hahha, but it will work :D (under "normal" conditions) ..  1: it is a drop-down .. 2: it does update as OP wants, so, no throwing stones... cuz -- you can't touch this ♪

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, the key issue as you have mentioned is need for refreshing the page, which reset other parameters on the page. A text file with the list files which stays "current" is already generated.  The question is how get the drop down list updated without having to refresh the page. Something like refreshing a <div> pseudo-continuously as long as the page is open.

Comment: @dawnz :: That was helpful, thanks. The solution is quite simple really; all you need is a persistent _ajax_ connection; (XMLHttpRequest), or at least making a request every half second - to this text file, parsing it with JavaScript on each "automatic refresh" (the ajax).. I can post a good answer for you that will definitely work - no manual refresh needed. -- although, I will need more info about the contents of this text file of yours so I can make a working example for you ;)

Comment: @dawnz :: maybe update your question with the info you shared here in the comments, mentioning AJAX, and specifying the data of this text file, maybe even copy+paste a sample line from this text file? This way I can update the answer and you'll have a working prototype real quick.

Comment: :: Thanks argon for your help. I use fwrite($fp,$value."\n"); to write the value associated with each key to the text file.   The text file therefore contains the name of each file in the public directory, per line.  Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: No sweat - the answer is updated, if you have any issues with the code I'll walk you through it, or i'll fix if broken, but see if you can manage, I'm sure you will. If this answer helped you solve the problem, don't forget to mark as correct (click the tick-mark under the triangular arrows where you vote an answer).